# Does resolve/reject exist promise?

Tags: javascript

Here is a demo promise I wrote:

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("I guess this message can be sent because it is because the 'resolve'");
  resolve('Promise was resolved!');
  console.log('But this message should not be shown from my point of view. Is not it?');
  reject('Promise was rejected!');
  console.log('Even this message was sent???');
});

console.log(promise); // Promise { 'Promise was resolved!' }
```

As you can see the code above printed all messages.

But how is it possible? I guess resolve/reject should works as return. Is't it?

1. Am I using `new Promise()` incorrectly?
2. Otherwise should I wrote all code before the resolve/reject from a readability point of view?

Comment: Calling resolve or reject is **not** the same thing is returning from the function, just as calling any _other_ function wouldn't be; neither throws an error.

Comment: "*I guess resolve/reject should works as return.*" Conceptually, it is *similar* in that it passes information/data back to the calling context, but `return` stops the execution of the function it's a part of, whereas `resolve` and `reject` do not (as you found).

Comment: `resolve()` and `reject()` basically just set flags in the `Promise` object, which can be used later when you call `.then()` or `.catch()` on the promise.